# Find text in gtk.TextView

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I have a `gtk.Textview`. I want to find and select some of the text in this `TextView` programmatically. 
I have this code but it's not working correctly.

```
search_str =  self.text_to_find.get_text()
start_iter =  textbuffer.get_start_iter() 
match_start = textbuffer.get_start_iter() 
match_end =   textbuffer.get_end_iter() 
found =       start_iter.forward_search(search_str,0, None) 
if found: 
   textbuffer.select_range(match_start,match_end)
```

If the text is found, then it selects all the text in the `TextView`, but I need it to select only the found text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`start_iter.forward_search` returns a tuple of the start and end matches so your `found` variable has both `match_start` and `match_end` in it

this should make it work:

```
search_str =  self.text_to_find.get_text()
start_iter =  textbuffer.get_start_iter()
# don't need these lines anymore
#match_start = textbuffer.get_start_iter() 
#match_end =   textbuffer.get_end_iter() 
found =       start_iter.forward_search(search_str,0, None) 
if found:
   match_start,match_end = found #add this line to get match_start and match_end
   textbuffer.select_range(match_start,match_end)
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, you realy helped me!